Why does implicit differentiation fail when using it to solve an equation?
Suppose that I have two real-valued functions
$f(x):=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$ and $g(x):=x^2 - 1$
and I want to find their intersection points when both are graphed on the Cartesian plane.
For each intersection point $P(x_i,y_i)$, what this means algebraically is that $P$ is on both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Hence, it needs to satisfy the constraints set by both functions:
$$y_i = f(x_i), y_i = g(x_i)$$
$$y_i = f(x_i) = g(x_i)$$
$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x_i) = x_i^2 - 1$$
Graphing $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ reveals that they intersect at $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$:

When solving this by hand though, it is not clear where to start. Therefore, I decided to start with the relation
$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x) = x^2 - 1 \rightarrow \textrm{(1)}$$
and took the second derivative of both sides:
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}[\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)] = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}[x^2 - 1]$$
$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x) = -\frac{8}{\pi^2} \rightarrow \textrm{(2)}$$
In (1) I get the intersections $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$, but in (2) I get
$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x) = -\frac{8}{\pi^2}$$
$$\frac{\pi}{2}x = \cos^{-1}(-\frac{8}{\pi^2}) + 2\pi n \,\,\,\, \textrm{or} \,\, -\cos^{-1}(-\frac{8}{\pi^2}) + 2\pi n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$x = \frac{2}{\pi}\cos^{-1}(-\frac{8}{\pi^2}) + 4 n \,\,\,\, \textrm{or} \,\, -\frac{2}{\pi}\cos^{-1}(-\frac{8}{\pi^2}) + 4 n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
i.e. a nonsensical answer.
But why doesn't taking the second derivative work out, even though implicit differentiation is valid for a relation like $x^2+y^2=9$?

The two sides would need to be equal at more than just a point, like an interval or maybe have the same derivative at that point

Two functions being equal does not mean their derivatives are equal.

You can clearly see in the very graph you posted that the functions don't have the same derivative (slope) or the same second derivative (curvature, which is zero for cos at those points but not for the parabola which always have non-zero constant second derivative).

does one example exist where one can solve an equation by taking derivatives?  honest question...

How about the same situation simplified to polynomials - even better between a parabola and a line?
let $(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb Q^4$
the intersection point between the graphs of
$$x^2+ax+b\quad \text{and}\quad cx+d \quad \text{are}$$
$$\left(\frac{c-a\pm D}{2},\frac{c^{2}-ac+2d\pm cD}{2}\right)\quad \text{with}\quad D=\sqrt{\left(a-c\right)^{2}-4\left(b-d\right)}$$
the intersection point of their derivatives is
$$\left(\frac{c-a}{2},c\right)$$
So for your method of taking the derivative to solve an equation to work here, you need
$$D=0,\qquad \land \qquad c^2-ac+2d=2c$$
$$\left(a-c \right)^2=4b-4d\quad \land \quad c\left(c-a-2\right)+2d=0 $$
one way to satisfy these conditions is if you have
$$b=\left(\frac{a-c}{2}\right)^{2}+\frac{c\left(a-c+2\right)}{2}\quad \land \quad d=\frac{c\left(a-c+2\right)}{2}$$
so the most general way this could happen is if your line and parabola are defined like so:
$$x^{2}+ax+\left(\frac{a-c}{2}\right)^{2}+\frac{c\left(a-c+2\right)}{2}\quad \land \quad cx+\frac{c\left(a-c+2\right)}{2}$$
needed to manufacture this result though, and generality is lost:  making $D$ vanish amounts to one intersection point between the line and the parabola - making it tangent, so now when you vary $a$, its the same as a horizontal shift, while varying c shifts you along the line $cx+d$.... in general you can't solve an equation by differentiating both sides....
